# ObservableCollection does not trigger propertyChanged in MAUI

Tags: xamarin, maui

I have a custom DataGrid control. Binding data to Itemsource is working fine.
NoDataView should be invisible if data is there in the item source.
The problem is when I add some items using Add it does not trigger PropertyChange event but when I assign a new list object to it triggers an event.

```
public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemsSource), typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(DataGrid), null,
    propertyChanged: (b, o, n) =>
    {
        if (!(b is DataGrid self)) return;

        if (self.SelectedItems == null)
        {
            self.SelectedItems = new List<object>();
        }

        if (o != null && o is INotifyCollectionChanged changed)
            changed.CollectionChanged -= self.HandleItemsSourceCollectionChanged;

        if (n != null)
        {
            if (n is INotifyCollectionChanged collectionChanged)
                collectionChanged.CollectionChanged += self.HandleItemsSourceCollectionChanged;

            var items = ((IEnumerable)n).Cast<DataGridRowModel>().ToList();
            // if (items.Count > 100) items = items.Take(100).ToList();
            self.InternalItems = items;
        }

        if (self.NoDataView != null)
        {
            if (self.ItemsSource == null || self.InternalItems?.Count == 0)
                self.NoDataViewElement.IsVisible = true;
            else if (self.NoDataViewElement.IsVisible)
                self.NoDataViewElement.IsVisible = false;
        }
        
    });


   private ObservableCollection<ItemModel> _result = new ObservableCollection<ItemModel>();
 public ObservableCollection<ItemModel> Result
 {
     get => _result;
     set { _result = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
 }



   private void BindItem(List<ItemModel> pDataTable)
 {
     try
     {
         if (pDataTable == null || pDataTable.Count == 0) return;

         foreach (var dr1 in pDataTable.Where()))
         {
             Results.Add(dr1);
         }
         //Results = Result;
         OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Results));
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         
     }
 }
```

> When Results.Add(dr1); it calls the
> HandleItemsSourceCollectionChanged but it is not going inside this
> below block which is responsible for hiding the nodataView element if there is data.

```
 if (self.NoDataView != null)
{
    if (self.ItemsSource == null || self.InternalItems?.Count == 0)
        self.NoDataViewElement.IsVisible = true;
    else if (self.NoDataViewElement.IsVisible)
        self.NoDataViewElement.IsVisible = false;
}
```

> On the other hand, if I create another ObservableCollection property
> i.e. Result, and assign the Result into the Results object it works
> fine means goes inside the if (self.NoDataView != null)

```
Result.Add(dr1);
Results = Result//Works fine
```

Can someone please help

Comment: ObservableCollection does not raise PropertyChanged events, it raises CollectionChanged events

Comment: yes right, it is calling HandleItemsSourceCollectionChanged as expected. So you mean to say I have to write if (self.NoDataView != null) inside HandleItemsSourceCollectionChanged. In Xamarin same code works fine.

Comment: Did you try write `if(self.NoDataView != null){}` in `HandleItemSourceCollectionChanged`?   Can this successfully trigger it?

Comment: @SeanHe-MSFT But declaration of self is in property change
if (!(b is DataGrid self)) return;
so can't find a way to write there

Comment: According to your description, the `HandleItemsSourceCollectionChanged` works normally, which means that when using `Result.Add( )`, `PropertyChanged` will be triggered first and then the `HandleItemsSourceCollectionChanged`, right? In addition, the `if (self.NoDataView != null)` will only be triggered when it is called for the first time, that is, when the `DataGrid` is empty. Afterwards, due to the `DataGrid` is not empty and the `NoDataView` is null, this code block will not be triggered.